# Unable to open a published MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish

I'm a total beginner so sorry in advance.

I used VS13 to build a MVC project and published it to my webspace. Now I'm unsure which file or path I need to specify in my forwarding config in order to open the website.

I tried

```
/Views/Shared
```

to get _Layout.cshtml and

```
/Views/Home
```

to get Index.cshtml but none of these are working. I also changed some admissions but it always shows me this

```
Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

when I'm trying to open the website.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you get over this?

Answer (score 0):

With MVC You don't access views like traditional ASP.NET WebForms i.e. `/path/to/view.aspx`. Everything is handled via routing & controllers.

By default you will have a `HomeController` which will have an `Index` action which is invoked via a `GET` request. Assuming you haven't changed any of the default routing configuration you would just need to navigate to `www.domainname.com/home` to see your `Index` page.

The default routing configuration looks like `/controller/action/parameters`, MVC will always work this way unless you tell it different. If you don't pass a specific action (like I didn't with the `home` url) the `Index` action of the controller is assumed.